# What does $( ) mean in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I encounter this when I am reading code from apache-spark:

```
    val alpha = new DoubleParam(this, "alpha", "alpha for implicit preference",
                                ParamValidators.gtEq(0)) 
    /** @group getParam */
    def getAlpha: Double = $(alpha)
```

I have searched for a long time in the web but still cannot find good explanation of what does `$(alpha)` mean here? How can it assign a self-defined class `DoubleParam` variable to `Double`? Thanks!!

FYI, The `DoubleParam` class is defined as:

```
class DoubleParam(parent: String, name: String, doc: String, isValid: Double => Boolean)
  extends Param[Double](parent, name, doc, isValid) {

  def this(parent: String, name: String, doc: String) =
    this(parent, name, doc, ParamValidators.alwaysTrue)

  def this(parent: Identifiable, name: String, doc: String, isValid: Double => Boolean) =
    this(parent.uid, name, doc, isValid)

  def this(parent: Identifiable, name: String, doc: String) = this(parent.uid, name, doc)

  /** Creates a param pair with the given value (for Java). */
  override def w(value: Double): ParamPair[Double] = super.w(value)
}
```

Comment: Please check the link which defines scala symbols: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-symbols.html

Comment: @RahulGopi in fact it has nothing to do with scala per se. It's syntax introduced by 3rd party library, likely by spark

Comment: @om-nom-nom I actually assumed this FAQ would explain it and describe how to look for such methods in Scaladoc, but it doesn't.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov [it's good that they accept PRs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/contribute.html)

Comment: @om-nom-nom: even though Scala *does* have macros now, you cannot introduce syntax in a third-party library. (You *can* introduce new *semantics* for *existing* syntax, though.) It's just a method like any other method.

Comment: @JörgWMittag sure. What I meant is that external library may define something akin to `object $ { def apply(x: Int) = ??? }` whereas scala does not have anything in it's core that might be invoked as `$(alpha)`

Comment: @om-nom-nom Thanks for the hint, done: https://github.com/scala/scala.github.com/pull/445

Comment: @om-nom-nom: Calling it "syntax", when it is just a method (or an object with `apply`) may give the impression that you can't look it up in ScalaDoc, when you can just hover over it in your IDE and it will show you. Even "magic" compiler-intrinsic classes such as `Int` have (fake) implementations and thus ScalaDoc, the only thing which doesn't have ScalaDoc is syntax, the type system, and the evaluation semantics; those have to looked up in the SLS. Everything else is in ScalaDoc, including the method asked about in the question: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#index.index-_

Comment: Thank you all for you answer!! : )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$()` is a Spark function defined in the trait `Params`. It simply calls `getOrDefault` on the `Params` object.

It's definition is

```scala
/** An alias for [[getOrDefault()]]. */
protected final def $[T](param: Param[T]): T = getOrDefault(param)
```

Comment: Thanks!! It is exactly what I want!

Comment: Great to hear @PunyTitan. If you're satisfied with an answer then you can simply accept it as the answer to your question in order to show your gratitude :-)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, in Spark 2.2.0 it's in `spark\mllib\src\main\scala\org\apache\spark\ml\param\params.scala`